# Does SystemVerilog have (others=>'0') expression like VHDL?

Tags: verilog, vhdl, system-verilog

In VHDL, we can set all bits of something a value by using `(others=>'0')`. It is also possible to use slice index e.g., `(7 downto 4) <= (others=>'1')`. How is this done in SystemVerilog?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, SystemVerilog supports:

```
data = '0;
data = '1;
data[7:4] = '0;
data[7:4] = '1;
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 5.7.1 *Integer literal constants*:

> An unsized single-bit value can be specified by preceding the
> single-bit value with an apostrophe ( ' ), but without the base
> specifier. All bits of the unsized value shall be set to the value of
> the specified bit. In a self-determined context, an unsized single-bit
> value shall have a width of 1 bit, and the value shall be treated as
> unsigned.
>
> '0, '1, 'X, 'x, 'Z, 'z // sets all bits to specified value

Answer (score 2):

SystemVerilog does not have an exact mapping of the VHDL `others <=` assignment construct. There are different approaches depending on whether you are dealing with packed arrays (integral types) or unpacked arrays, or if you want to assign the entire signal or different pieces of the signal.

For a packed array assignment of all bits, you can use the fill literals `'0`, `'1`, `'x`, or `'z`.

```
signal = '1; // sets all bit of signal to 1
```

You can use adjacent assignments to get the effect of a compound assignment

```
begin
  signal     <= '0; // others <= '0'
  signal[7:4]<= something_else;
end
```

For unpacked arrays, you can use an *assignment pattern* with a `default` key. Assignment pattern look like Verilog concatenations, but preceded with a `'{}`.

```
logic [7:0] array[9:0];

array = '{4:'hAA, 7:'1, default:'z}};
```

This sets `array[4]` to 8'hAA, `array[7]` to 8'hFF, and the remaining 8 elements to 8'hzz.

There is no corresponding range key in an assignment pattern, but you can use a combination of assignments shown above to get the functionality you are looking for

```
begin
   array      = '{default:'0}; // all elements to 0
   array[7:4] = '{default:'1}; // elements 7 downto 4 set to 8'hff
end
```

See section *10.9.1 Array assignment patterns* in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595) for a number of other things you can do.